# Funding after getting an Integrated Masters Degree

Tags: masters, funding, career-path, university, united-kingdom

Im going to get my **Integrated Masters Degree in Production Engineering and Management** in about 6 months.My next goal is to take another Master's Degree in Artificial Intelligence.The country I want to study is the UK.So will i be eligible for a **postgraduate** student loan even though I have an **integrated** master's degree ?

Comment: Best people to ask would be SLC (the student loans company). But as far as I know and integrated Masters counts as an undergraduate degree and you're therefore elegible for a postgraduate loan.

Comment: I think that this kind of loans are delivered by the UK Government and not a specific company.

Comment: The SLC is the government owned company which deals with student loans for UK students. Do you definitely mean a loan and not a stipend or bursary?

Comment: I googled "postgradute student loans eligibility" and found the [relevant government website](https://www.gov.uk/postgraduate-loan). This should give you all the information you need...

Comment: Yeap I know the website.I was just asking to check if there are any exceptions not mentioned there.The website states that if you own a master's degree or an equivalent or higher qualification you are not eligible for a postgraduate loan .Hitting the link of "equivalent or higher" gets you to a page that ranks the education in levels.The integrated master's degree is on the same level as a regular master's degree so therefore I will not be eligible.Is that right ?I have to state that Im not a resident of the Uk .I live in greece .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching on various goverment websites, it turned out [Find a Masters](https://www.findamasters.com/funding/guides/postgraduate-loan-apply.aspx) had the answer.

You are **not** eligible for a UK postgraduate student loan if you already hold an integrated Master's degree.